# Kotlin DSL build scripts dependency updates

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

There has been a myriad of articles written about how migrating from using groovy scripts to using Kotlin DSL for Gradle dependency management is an ideal way to manage build scripts among other mentioned advantages.

However, the limitation that I have found is the lack of this Gradle management way or process in highlighting when new versions of the current dependencies are available as was done previously using groovy scripts. The current solutions that I have found include the use of plugins or utilities that scan through your buildSrc folder and provide the updates as comments to the current versions of the libraries. Some of which include the following:

[buildSrcVersions](https://github.com/jmfayard/buildSrcVersions)

[Gradle-versions-plugin](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin)

Apart from the few plugins that I have mentioned is there any other efficient methods of checking for dependency updates?

Comment: I'm also looking for the same solution.

Comment: @Aroniez Have added a solution that works for me: let me know how you get on.

Comment: @George Do you still have this problem? I think the plugin I've mentioned below answers your question.

Comment: @dnh sure thing will try it out

Answer (score 3):

Best solution is to use [`gradle-versions-plugin`](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.ben-manes.versions).

This will add `dependencyUpdates` tasks, which will check available updates for both libraries and Gradle version itself. You can decide if you really on all available versions or filter everything non-stable.

You can run this task manually in e.g. before release or add as a build step. As a result you'll receive message with available updates.

It works for both gradle in groovy and gradle kotlin dsl.